# Trouble using the computer in the first turn-on

Tags: windows-7

The computer I have is a Inspiron 17 64.  Today, five year after buying this computer, I start to have to restart it after turning it on more and more. The computer just wouldn't open any application in the first turnon.

What solution do you guys suggest? ( or else I may I have to buy a new laptop)

PS: I should also make a mention of my forcing the computer to turn off and turning it on.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting it on **safe mode** (F8)and check whether there is any issue with the dll or with application. If you are not able to find the exact issue click F8 and boot it with "**restore previous good configuration**" option and check. Mostly the above will do the trick.

Some times you may face these kind of issues due to hard disk corruption. Check the disk health using dell Diagnostics option from bios.

- Boot your computer and hit F2 at the dell logo. Check in the BIOS
  setup menu and see if your hard drive is recognized.
- If so, then boot your computer and hit F12 when you see the Dell logo
  and select Dell Diagnostics and run Dell Diagnostics on the hard drive.

Hope this will do the trick.

Comment: Is the way to retrieve data is a hard disk is corrupted basically when computer will not turn on

Comment: yes we are having several options to do the needful. I suggest you to hand it over to technician who can do it in a professional way.

Comment: When I need to run safe mode? Isn't it just the same as normal mode I am always in?